# Synapse table -Copy Behaviour type in dataflow of ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I know in copy activity we can select the copy methods (copy command ,polybase,built-in). Among that first 2 types needed staging Storage account to load the data.

If you load synapse table through dataflow, by default it needs staging area. So it means its not built-in but which of the other two ?

just want to know how dataflow works :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dataflow in Azure Synapse Analytics uses PolyBase
PolyBase is a technique that can be used to access data stored in Azure Blob and Azure Data Lake storage.
Also PolyBase is a built-in feature in Azure Synapse Analytics that allows you to query and load data from external sources using T-SQL queries.

When you use Dataflow to load data into a Synapse table, it automatically creates a staging area in an Azure Blob Storage account.
The data is first loaded into the staging area and then moved to the target Synapse table using PolyBase.

So, to summarize, Dataflow in Azure Synapse Analytics uses the built-in PolyBase method for loading data into a Synapse table, and it requires a staging area in an Azure Blob Storage account.

Know more about [Data Flow activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-data-flow-activity#polybase)